# SQL Select where all related entries satisfy condition

Tags: sql, join, heroku-postgres

Table A:

```
id | name | type
```

Table B:

```
id | a_id | structure
```

where A has many B's.

I would like to query for all As where none of it's related entries in Table B has a structure = 'successful'

I am attempting to do

```
select a.name
from a
inner join b on a.id = b.a_id where a.type = 'note' and a.id = ALL (Select a_id from B where structure <> 'successful')
```

but I am getting 0 results. (Heroku Dataclips)

Sample Data

```
id | name | type
01 | woof | note
02 | meow | note
03 | who  | free

id | a_id | structure
01 | 01 | open
02 | 01 | draft
03 | 02 | draft
04 | 02 | successful
05 | 02 | open
06 | 03 | open
```

Running this query should return

```
woof
```

since I want all entities from A that has an associated type of note, but that none of it's related entries in table B has a structure = 'successful'

Comment: Did you at least give it a try, if so show us

Comment: TAG only the database you are actually using. Tags are there to attract the correct audience for your question

Comment: @DaleK Thank you. Didn't realize how to do it earlier. Also, I was attempting to do a a.id = ALL (Select a_id from B where structure <> 'x') but I was getting 0 results.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Noted. Also, my attempt is above.

Comment: @DaleK Completed. Also, I am using Heroku Dataclips. What would that be? Or do I tag as Heroku Dataclips? Sorry I read the SO guides awhile back and don't use it much...

Comment: Tag it if the tag exists, else mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `not exists` would satisfy your criteria?

```
select a.name
from TableA a
where a.type='note'
and not exists (select * from TableB b where b.a_id=a.id and b.structure='successful')
```

Result: **'woof'**

Comment: Same issue as above. I am no longer returning any query results.

Comment: Recommend you post sample data for your two tables and expected results.

Comment: I've updated with sample data and a better explanation.

Comment: @BenGarcia note I'm not using Heroku Dataclips but with your sample data using ansi sql it works fine and returns the expected 1 row, edited above in-line with data.

Comment: Thank you. I was inner joining table A and B instead of the where b.a_id = a.id and I thought that was equivalent. Thank you for the help.